# Как получить сумму чисел, находящихся в списке <li></li>?

Tags: javascript, html

Как получить сумму чисел в result, находящихся в списке li, нажатием кнопки?

```js
function add() {
  var liSum = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = liSum;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li> 100 </li>
    <li> 100 </li>
  </ul>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <input type="button" onclick="addUl()" value="Add" />
</body>

</html>
```

И чтоб когда нажатием кнопки выводился результат в result!
Помогите пожалуйста!.

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].reduce((a, {textContent})=>(a+=Number.parseInt(textContent, 10)), 0)`

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Посмотрите внимательно логи в консоли, есть ли там ошибки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` возвращает коллекци элементов. Как следствие: нужно циклом пробежаться по этой коллекции и сложить все значения, полученные на каждой итерации с итоговой переменной `sum`. изначально `sum` надо будет инициализировать нулём

Answer (score 1):

```js
const $result = document.getElementById(`result`);
const $li = document.getElementsByTagName(`li`);

document.getElementById(`i`).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < $li.length; i++) sum += parseInt($li[i].textContent);
  $result.innerHTML = sum.toString();
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 100 </li>
  <li> 100 </li>
</ul>
<p id="result"></p>
<input id="i" type="button" value="Add" />
```